# How to use an aggregate in a case statement in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to use an aggregated column in a case statement in Django and I am having no luck getting Django to accept it.

The code is to return a list of people who have played a game, the number of times they have played the game and their total score. The list is sorted by total score descending. However, the game has a minimum number of plays in order to qualify. Players without sufficient plays are listed at the bottom. For example:

```
Player  Total  Plays
Jill      109     10
Sam        92     11
Jack       45      9
Sue        50      3
```

Sue is fourth in the list because her number of plays (3) is less than the minimum (5).

The relevant models and function are:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    min_plays = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Play(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)

class Score(models.Model):
    play = models.ForeignKey(Play)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    score = models.IntegerField()

def game_standings(game):
    query = Player.objects.filter(score__play__game_id=game.id)
    query = query.annotate(plays=Count('score', filter=Q(score__play__game_id=self.id)))
    query = query.annotate(total_score=Sum('score', filter=Q(score__play__game_id=self.id)))
    query = query.annotate(sufficient=Case(When(plays__ge=game.minimum_plays, then=1), default=0)
    query = query.order_by('-sufficient', '-total_score', 'plays')
```

When the last annotate method is hit, a "Unsupported lookup 'ge' for IntegerField or join on the field not permitted" error is reported. I tried to change the case statement to embed the count instead of using the annotated field:

```
query = query.annotate(
    sufficient=Case(When(
        Q(Count('score', filter=Q(score__play__game_id=game.id)))> 3, then=1), default=0
    )
)
```

but Django reports a TypeError with '>' and Q and int.

The SQL I am trying to get to is:

```
SELECT "player"."id",
       "player"."name",
       COUNT("score"."id") FILTER (WHERE "play"."game_id" = 8) AS "plays",
       SUM("score"."score") FILTER (WHERE "play"."game_id" = 8) AS "total_score",
       case when COUNT("score"."id") FILTER (WHERE "play"."game_id" = 8) >= 5 then 1
       else 0
       end as sufficient
FROM "player"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "score" ON ("player"."id" = "score"."player_id")
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "play" ON ("score"."play_id" = "play"."id")
WHERE "play"."game_id" = 8
GROUP BY "player"."id"
ORDER BY sufficent desc, total_score desc
```

I can't seem to figure out how to have the case statement use to play count.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case?

Comment: Actually there is no `ge` for this. You can use `gt - greater than` or `gte - greater than, equal`.

Comment: sigh. So sad I missed that. gte worked. Thanks.